# wordpress query acording to meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'post_type'         => 'movies',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'budget',
                'type'      => 'numeric'
            ),
        ),
    );

?>
```

I have tried to list my custom post type 'movies' according to their meta key 'budget', but for some reason it doesn't produce the correct output. e.g.

american hero  990,000
cop car  800,000
level up  400,000
spider-man iii  258,000,000
batman v superman : dawn of justice  250,000,000
captain america : civil war  250,000,000
captain america : civil war 3d  250,000,000
pirates of the caribbean : on stranger tides  250,000,000
avengers : age of ultron  250,000,000
john carter  250,000,000

first 3 are wrong but the rest are fine... help needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [order](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) parameter:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'post_type'         => 'movies',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'budget',
                'type'      => 'numeric'
            ),
        ),
    );

?>
```